# mocha and nested objects

Tags: ruby, testing, mocking, stubbing, ruby-mocha

Excuse if this is a silly question, I am new to mocking.

I am able to use mocha to do things like:

```
person.expects(:first_name).returns('David')
```

How can I mock a nested object?

Say I have a Product that belongs to a Person and I want to get the first name of that person.

In my app I might do it like this:

```
product.person.first_name
```

How would I get the same result using a mock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as an alternative to shingara's answer, you could use mocha's `any_instance` method "which will detect calls to any instance of a class".

```
Person.any_instance.expects(:first_name).returns('david')
```

it's documented at:
http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/ClassMethods.html#M000001

Answer (score 2):

you need define a mock() before and return it when you call person on product

```
person = mock(:first_name => 'david')
product.expects(:person).return(person)

product.person #=> mockObject
product.person.first_name #=> david
```