# Minitest/Mocha nested stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, minitest, stub

I want to stub a function that returns another stub using Mocha on Minitest.
This is the code

```
@instance = stub('instance') do
      stubs(:destroy).returns(true)
      stubs(:id).returns(0)
end
find_by_id = stub do 
      stubs(:find_by_id).returns(nil) #default
      stubs(:find_by_id).with(@instance.id).returns(@instance)
    end 
@user.stubs(:instances).returns(find_by_id)
```

When I run the code with byebug, @instance is defined:

```
(byebug) @instance
#<Mock:instance>
```

however, inside *find_by_id = stub do*

```
(byebug) @instance
nil
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378808/mocha-and-nested-objects) about using mock instead of stub, but that does not work either.

I don't get why @instance is nil inside the *do block*, being that it was previously defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently is under investigation. [source](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/286)

For now, I could fix it by simply using 'instance' instead of '@instance'.